# Is it possible to insert current datetime in a stored procedure which is designed to insert data?

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures, timestamp, getdate

I've created the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertTutees 
    @StudentID INT = NULL, 
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
    @Surname   VARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
    @Major     VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Timestamp DATETIME = NULL  
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    INSERT INTO dbo.Tutees (StudentID, FirstName, Surname, Major, Timestamp) 
    VALUES (@StudentID, @FirstName, @Surname, @Major, @Timestamp) 
END 
GO

EXEC dbo.InsertTutees 
         @StudentID = 2, 
         @FirstName = 'Sarah', 
         @Surname = 'Smith', 
         @Major = 'Science',
         @Timestamp = '2013-12-12';
```

However I would like to replace the timestamp value with the current timestamp. I've tried `GETDATE()`, but I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

Is there an alternative way to retrieve the current date inside this exec statement? Should I edit my stored procedure?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
This is the exec statement I try to complete:

```
EXEC dbo.InsertTutees
       @StudentID = 2, 
       @FirstName = 'Sarah' , 
       @Surname = 'Smith' , 
       @Major = 'Science' ,
       @Timestamp = getdate()
```

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code including `GETDATE()` that gave you the error message. Is it possible you were trying to pass in `GETDATE()` as a parameter to the stored procedure?

Comment: Added my attempted script which leads me to the above error. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an intermediate variable:

```
    DECLARE @dt datetime =GETDATE()

    EXEC dbo.InsertTutees
       @StudentID = 2, 
       @FirstName = 'Sarah' , 
       @Surname = 'Smith' , 
       @Major = 'Science' ,
       @Timestamp = @dt
```

Comment: Ah, misunderstood what you were asking for. Cool. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you look it up [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), a default has to be a constant or NULL. In order to have a default value that equates to GETDATE(), you'd need some code within the proc along these lines:

```
IF @Timestamp IS NULL
BEGIN
SET @Timestamp = GETDATE();
END
```

That would allow you to both provide a value and supply a default as needed.